Angular 17 AuthGuard with Observable
Trying to get the following AuthGuard to properly redirect if a user is not logged in.
export const authGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  const router = inject(Router);

  return authService.currentUser$.pipe(map((auth: User | null) => {
    console.log(auth);
    if(auth !== null){
      console.log(auth);
      return true;
    }
    return router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
  }));
};

and in my AuthService file I utilize the following
private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User | null>(1);
currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

In my app.routes.ts file my Test component is being lazy loaded.
{path: 'test', loadComponent: () => import('./test/test.component').then(mod => mod.TestComponent), canActivate: [authGuard]},

Instead of redirecting the user to a login page, it just shows a blank page.
Thanks
I have re-written it several times utilizing different methods, but they all failed at redirecting.

Is the route for the login page correct? I would recommend testing a direct return true or urlTree to see if the issue is the guard, or the auth service

The route is correct. I even moved the return statements to verify. If a user is logged in it will redirect to the login page. If a user is logged out the Guard still wont continue and shows a blank page, despite having a return true statement.

Can you setup a stackblitz to reproduce this?

What I think the problem may be is using a ReplaySubject for your currentUserSource variable, I would advice replacing it for a BehaviourSubject :
private currentUserSource = new BehaviourSubject<User | null>(null);
currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

As to why I believe this might be the source of the problem, a guard that causes a lock on an empty page usually means that its waiting for an Observable to emit a value.
A ReplaySubject holds no default value meaning that if no value was emitted before the guard is called, your authGuard will subscribe to an observable that will will never emit any value, which causes it to wait indefinitely.
Changing it to a BehaviourSubject will ensure that there is always a value, so the guard may always be able to complete.

Switching to BehaviorSubject worked.
What's the difference between BehaviorSubject and ReplaySubject?

A BehaviourSubject will always hold the last value that was emitted, thus when subscribing to one we will always get at least one value, a ReplaySubject is used to hold an arbitrary amount of values for a defined amount of time, it is not guaranteed to get a value when subscribing to one.

Kind of, now its always returning as Null even though a user is logged in.

I tried to replicate your issue on stackblitz, and when using functional guards, I was running into the "no provider for authguard", in which would return a black page.
So I turned the functional authguard into a class guard, and provided in root
See here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-standalone-route-fhto46?file=src%2Froutes%2Froutes.ts

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class AuthGuardClass implements CanActivate {
  private router = inject(Router);
  canActivate() {
    return of({ user: 'mock' }).pipe( // Replace mock
      map((auth: { user: string } | null) => {
        console.log(auth);
        if (auth !== null) {
          console.log(auth);
          return true;
        }
        return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
      })
    );
  }
}

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardClass],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'home',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./home.component').then((mod) => mod.HomeComponent),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./login.component').then((mod) => mod.LoginComponent),
  },
];


I created a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-htyo1n?file=src%2Findex.html

The reason why the CanActivateFn is not working in your version is due to the Angular version, it was introduced in Angular 16, your Stackblitz is running Angular 14

I noticed it will return null, before pulling the data:
authService.currentUser$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));

  return authService.currentUser$.pipe(
    map((auth: any) => {
    console.log(auth);
    if(auth){
      console.log(auth);
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log(auth);
      return router.parseUrl('/login');
    }
  }));

Which results in the following for AuthGuard and my other checks
null auth.guard.ts:11 null
null auth.guard.ts:15 null
null auth.guard.ts:20 null
// And then we finally load before the redirect
auth.guard.ts:11 {uuid: 1, email: 'user@example.com'}

This is what I have in my app.components.ts
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCurrentUser();
  }

  loadCurrentUser(){
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if(user) {
      this.authService.loadCurrentUser(user).subscribe({
        next: () => { console.log('loader user') },
        error: (e: any) => {
          localStorage.removeItem('user');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
         },
        complete: () => { console.log('completed') }
      });
    }
  }

and this is what I have in my authService
loadCurrentUser(user: string | null): Observable<any> {

    if (user === null) {
      this.currentUserSource.next(null);
      return of(null);
    }

    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseURI + '/auth').pipe(
      map((user: User) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
          return user;
        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem('user');
          this.currentUserSource.next(null);
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }

This is observed on a page refresh or a user returning back to the site.

Not sure if this was the best solution or not; but what I did was removed the NgOnInit and loadCurrentUser from app.components.ts. Then created a new file called app.init.ts with the following
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AuthService } from "./services/auth.service";

export function loadCurrentData(router: Router, authService: AuthService) {
  const user = localStorage.getItem('user');
  if(user) {
    return () => authService.loadCurrentUser(user);
  }
  return () => null;
}

and added the following to my app.config.ts file:
{
   provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
   useFactory: loadCurrentData,
   multi: true,
   deps:[Router, AuthService],
},

Now I just need to account for a 401 error in the following code and redirect to the login page. This is caused by a user deleting the cookies, but not the localStorage item:
loadCurrentUser(user: string | null): Observable<any> {

    console.log('Load user has been called');

    if (user === null) {
      this.currentUserSource.next(null);
      return of(null);
    }

    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseURI + '/auth').pipe(
      map((user: User) => {
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSource.next(user);
        }
      })
    );
  }


Instead of creating an APP_INITIALIZER function, you could have called the loadCurrentUser in your auth.service.ts in its constructor.

If I try to add constructor () {}; to auth.guard.ts I get the following error: Cannot find name 'constructor'. unless you mean adding it to the constructor of auth.service.ts
